# Bootstrap input-group -> input with addon & help text, addon height?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a HTML input.
The small help text i populate with Jquery.
My problem is that the `input-group-addon` height will stretch all way down to the `small`element. I´d like it to be as high as the input.
How can i solve this?

```
<div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group-addon">Obj. Nr</div>
     <input type="text" class="form-control">
     <small class="form-text text-muted"></small>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `small` element after `input`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">Obj. Nr</div>
       <input type="text" class="form-control">     
  </div>
  <small class="form-text text-muted">Small element</small>
</div>
```